# Return all values from IN Clause on SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, union

Is there a way to retrieve all the data from an `IN` clause?

Let's assume my table got (ID,Name):

`0 Banana`
`1 Mango`
`2 Papaya`
`3 Lemon`

and my query:

```
SELECT * FROM Fruits WHERE Name IN (Banana,Mango,Orange)
```

I Want 'Orange' to return, with an empty ID (since there's no register). How to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the `IN` clause for this. You would need to get the target fruits into a table that you can outer join against.

```
SELECT ...
FROM 
(SELECT 'Banana' AS fruit UNION ALL SELECT 'Mango' UNION ALL SELECT 'Orange') f 
LEFT JOIN Fruits ON Fruits.Name = f.fruit
```

Or Option 2 (as long as your list is <= 8000 characters). Create a UDF [like the one here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/training/scripts/userdefinedfunction/) (but using `varchar(8000)` instead of `varchar(max)`). Then use it as follows.

```
SELECT ...
FROM dbo.fnSplitStringList('Banana,Mango,Orange') f 
LEFT JOIN Fruits ON Fruits.Name = f.StringLiteral
```

Comment: Alright, lets assume i got over 1500 registers, theres a better way to do this?

Comment: @alex - You could pass them in as a comma delimited list and use a split table valued function (e.g. [dbo.fnSplitStringList](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/training/scripts/userdefinedfunction/) here) that you then join against. Or pass them in as XML possibly. Not sure what SQL2000 support is like for that option.

Comment: Nah, sql2000 really sucks, i wish i was on Oracle :| Anyone else?

Comment: How would you do this on Oracle?

Comment: I would create a temp table, i just dont have enough permissions on this god damned sql server. heh.

Comment: @alex - You should be able to create a table variable in SQL Server 2000 regardless of your permissions. (Possibly a `#temp` table as well - I think anyone can create those)

Answer (score 0):

Right join by name, but you need a separate table with names.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it once, I wrote a program, it simplifies creating the "IN" clause, here: [InClauseCreator](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/inclausecreator). If, however, you are doing it regularly, then you'd be better off importing data into a temp table and then doing a left join, close to what Martin Smith suggested.